# Need to reshape pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

My input dataframe looks like this:

```
Variable | fiscal_week_id | units 
xxxxxxxxxxx | 201801 | xx_unit_201801 
xxxxxxxxxxx | 201802 | xx_unit_201802 
xxxxxxxxxxx | 201803 | xx_unit_201803 
yyyyyyyyyyy | 201801 | yy_unit_201801 
yyyyyyyyyyy | 201802 | yy_unit_201802 
yyyyyyyyyyy | 201803 | yy_unit_201803
```

---

Need output like this:

```
Variable | 201801 | 201802 | 201803 
xxxxxxxxxxx | xx_unit_201801 | xx_unit_201802 | xx_unit_201803 
yyyyyyyyyyy | yy_unit_201801 | yy_unit_201802 | yy_unit_201803
```

Any help please, new to pandas and need solution in pandas only. I tried out with `set_index`, but didn't seem to work out.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`pd.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) as @jezrael suggests:

```
res = df.pivot(index='Variable', columns='fiscal_week_id', values='units')

print(res)

fiscal_week_id          201801          201802          201803
Variable                                                      
xxxxxxxxxxx     xx_unit_201801  xx_unit_201802  xx_unit_201803
yyyyyyyyyyy     yy_unit_201801  yy_unit_201802  yy_unit_201803
```

---

Previous attempt:

You can use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html). When you don't have a "real" aggregation function, you can use [`'first'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first.html) to extract the only item:

```
res = df.pivot_table(index='Variable', columns='fiscal_week_id',
                     values='units', aggfunc='first')
```

Comment: @jezrael, Never used it myself tbh! Feel free to add a solution.

Comment: So check dupe, `pivot` is faster like `pivot_table`

Comment: and aggfunc='first' is really specific reasons, so not sure if good idea here.

Comment: @jezrael, True, I'm reading the pivot vs pivot_table post, you're probably right.

Comment: Ya, a bit surprise you dont know about `pivot`... ;)

Comment: but i need "Variable" in the output columns with fiscal_week_id.

Comment: @saswatasen, Not sure what you mean. This matches your desired output. If column headings are your issue, there are *many* duplicates relating to this.

Comment: basically i need the dtypes as : Variable object,201801 object, 201802 object, 201803 object. Can I achieve this? @jpp

Comment: Just use `reset_index` afterwords.